# Show that the solution to $\ddot x + \sin(x) = 0$ exists globally

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to show the solution to the equation in the title exists globally. I believe we are supposed to used "a priori" knowledge to show this rather than a rigorous proof. To get started, I multiplied the equation by $\dot x$ to get

$$\ddot x \dot x + \dot x\sin(x) = 0$$

Then I integrated with respect to $t$ , to get

$$\frac{\dot x^2}{2} - \cos{x} = C$$

The $\cos{x}$ is tripping me up a bit. I can't figure out why the solution would exist globally from this. I'm pretty sure this is the method to use, as the examples in the text are using this method. If I can just show that $|x| \lt K$  where $K$ is just some new constant, then I'd be good, but I'm not seeing it. I think I also have to show $|\dot x| \lt C$ but I'm not 100% sure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't local lipschitz (picard lindelöf) give you a global solution ?

Comment: Yes but like I said, I want to use the specified method to show it is bounded if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\dfrac{\dot{x}^2}{2} - \cos x = C$ you get that $|\dot{x}| \le \sqrt{|C| + 1}$, and hence $|x| \le |x(0)| + |t| \sqrt{|C|+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your problem is Hamiltonian or, if you prefer, a Newton problem with potential $V(x)=-\cos(x)$. (Actually, it models a pendulum...) Why not resort to a phase plane analysis?

Comment: because of how simple the selected correct answer is

Comment: I didn't mean *instead of* the 1st answer, but as motivation for it. A phase plane analysis shows exactly that the orbits remain bounded in the vertical ($\dot{x}$) direction, which can lead one to look for such a bound even in cases (read: other ODEs) where a bound may be less forthcoming/the algebra can be daunting. Simple problems as the pendulum above serve little purpose in a curriculum if not as springboards for treating more complex cases. That's a POV, of course.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm not doubting there's better ways to more fully prove this. Phase planes are great for analysis. Could also use Lipshitz conditions and Picard Existence theorem to prove it I believe...